# Notepad++ Find string 'a', delete line and subsequent line(s) until string 'b' is found

Tags: notepad++

I am editing a GEDCOM file and removing 'bad' GEDCOM tags. My example is :-
I want to search for '2 RIN', delete that line and all subsequent lines until the first characters on the next line is '1 ' (1 + a space). The line with '1 ' should not be deleted.

An example:

Existing file

```
1 DEAT
2 TYPE D02 Death
2 DATE 1960
2 PLAC Perth
2 RIN 2
2 _PPT @@I1@@
3 TYPE 0 event owner
3 _NSQ 0
1 BURI
2 TYPE D04 Death, Burial
2 PLAC Australia
```

should result as:

```
1 DEAT
2 TYPE D02 Death
2 DATE 1600
2 PLAC Perth
1 BURI
2 TYPE D04 Death, Burial
2 PLAC Australia
```

Answer (score 2):

regex `^.*RIN.*\r\n(.*\r\n)*(?=^1.*)`
or a bit better
regex `^.*RIN.*\r\n(.*\r\n)*(?=^1 .*)`

so there's your regx. replace that with nothing. or with \r\n

**Added**
An explanation. `^` Match the beginning of a line then `.*` any and all characters(though not new line 'cos we ticked that dot doesn't match new line box) then  `(.*\r\n)*` match all lines after UNTIL this thing that you don't match.  (?=^1 .*)  So lookahead just to what's immediately coming up as the next character but this time, don't match it, and look for the line beginning with 1 then space then whatever. IF when looking you find that, then match the position.

So see that everything the regex identifies, is matched. From the text identified at the start of the regex, to the regex lookahead that identifies a position to match, and is at the end of  the regex.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Slight correction to the above.

A)You asked re lines beginning with "2 RIN".
B)It needed a non-greedy evaluation for one of the *s so that it matches before the first occurrence of ^1.
C)You need to consider whether the file has *nix or Windows line endings. You can do a find in the document and look for \r\n  or for \n, and see what matches, to see which line endings the file uses. That's one way. Your file has *nix line endings as is shown on the bottom right of the notepad++ window.

So you want this regex `^2 RIN.*\n(.*\n)*?(?=^1.*)`

You would want this one if it were Windows line endings  which can happen if you were copy/pasting, then you'd want this regex  `^2 RIN.*\r\n(.*\r\n)*?(?=^1.*)`

But opening the file or a copy of the file directly, for sure, you want the \n version, the *nix version i.e. `^2 RIN.*\n(.*\n)*?(?=^1.*)`  Because the windows software writing the file, is writing it with *nix style line endings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am a complete novice at Notepad++, I can't seem to find a manual anywhere to explain the switches etc. so I am a bit lost. I 'copy and pasted' your command but it selected the whole document when used. But thank you for your prompt answer and I notice that my question has been edited - thanks for that, it is much esaier for others to understand - but I didn't type t in like that :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am a complete novice at Notepad++ and can't seem to find a manual anywhere to explain the parameters and switches on the command line to decipher what is going on. I 'copy and pasted' the details and it selected the whole file, including the parts before the first occurrence of '1 RIN'.

Comment: @DavidBanks Did you include the `^` at the beginning of the regular expression. And did you untick the box that says `.` matches newline?  By the way, this is what your question looked like before my edit http://i.imgur.com/sgk0Du6.png     So stackoverflow doesn't display questions as they are typed, it messes up the formatting, so I fixed the formatting to make it appear as you typed it.

Comment: @DavidBanks rre you looking for a manual.  egular expressions aren't specific to notepad++  I suggest a good interactive quiz  to help learn them.  e.g. http://regexone.com/  and as a manual/reference http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Yes, I included the ^ and unticked the '.matches new line' box. I pasted the command line and even typed it in myself but it still selects the whole document of 85,000 lines. The first occurrence of 'RIN' is on line 106 yet it selects the whole document. Help!Thanks for retyping my original message, it made complete nonsense when I saw what had happened - in the 21st century we seem to have lost WYSIWYG! Preserving formatting surely should be a fundamental feature. And I didn't realise when you hit 'return' it 'sends' this message!

Comment: @DavidBanks  What if you just put `RIN` in the search box, and click "find" does it select the entire document?  If not, then try `RIN.*` and then same question, did it select the entire document? i.e. you find what what point it makes the error of selecting the entire document

Comment: Hi, it  highlights 9095 occurrences of RIN when I do a normal search starting at line 106. Adding the .* walks me through the whole file (I presume, I didn't do it 9095 times) selecting each RIN plus anything on that line from line 106 also.

Comment: @DavidBanks That file is about 12 lines long it doesn't have 9095 occurrences of RIN  doesn't that seem a bit strange to you?!

Comment: Hi, that was just an example of what I am trying to do, the total length of the file is 85648 lines long.

Comment: @DavidBanks well try it on a simple small example file.. see if it works on that first. Then if it does your question would be why it works on the small file and doesn't work on the big one  You could try halving your big file, then trying it on it. Keep halving it make your big file as small as possible while still producing the problem. Eventually you might narrow in on where the problem is. That's basic troubleshooting

Comment: Hi, did what you suggested and when I got down to 190 lines it found the first RIN but selected right down to the last '1 ' in the file, not the next one - and there were lines remaining. So it seems not to stop when it finds the next '1 ' but only stops looking when there are none left. Just a few things about a GEDCOM file: There is always a numeric plus a space in the first column. Each record starts at a zero, data is nested by incrementing the first numeric, normally 1 to 4 levels would be reached and then it may decrease back to 1 followed by a zero to denote the next record.

Comment: @DavidBanks are you able to share this file i.e. put it on http://ge.tt  or link to it on dropbox?

Comment: Hi, the file has details of living people, if I put it on ge.tt who will be able to 'get' at it?

Comment: @DavidBanks ok don't put it there.  I guess you can't easily do a find and replace to remove/change names.. How about if you create a small GEDCOM file with some dummy data but with the same problem with RIN?

Comment: Hi, I'm doing a mass replace of the significant names, will send it soon.

Comment: Hi, I've put it on ge.tt, do I need to tell you where it is, I have copied the link or can you find it via my email? Let me know when you have taken a copy then I will remove it.

Comment: @DavidBanks  remove it from ge.tt  a more private way is look at my profile http://superuser.com/users/42672/barlop?tab=profile   I just put an EM address in there  `r....yahoo.co.uk` for you to send the file to. I'll keep it up there for a few days / until I get the EM from you.